# Disable mod_python error and traceback

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu

I want to disable mode_python error, traceback, module cache details and any other warning notice !

I am using simple mod_python module on ubuntu server with apache, without any framework (Django ect ...).

I made lot of searchs on GOOGLE but no one speak about this :)

I want alternative to `error_reporting(0);` on PHP or any config changes on the server side.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Heyy,

For ubuntu, this is what you can do:

sudo a2dismod mod_python

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I got this error: `ERROR: Module mod_python does not exist!` But i see that you want to disable mod_python ? I need it for web script !!! i want only to disable errors ...

Answer (score 0):

Here the answer:

```
vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

Modify:

```
PythonDebug On
```

To:

```
PythonDebug Off
```

And then

```
service apache2 restart
```

Done ;)